# regex expression for float conversion

Tags: c#, regex, decimal

I'm trying to convert a float to a string with C# regular expressions.

What i want is this.

a) if the value is 1234 i want 1234

b) if the value is 123.4 i want 123.4

c) if the value is 0.1234 i want 0.123

d) if the value is 12.0004 i want 12

I have this so far

```
{
    (?:\d*\.)[1-9]{0,3}
}
```

but this doesn't remove the dot at value d)

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: This is not a job for a regular expression

Comment: It's bot clear whether the generalization is "keep a maximum of three decimals" or "keep four significant digits". What about rounding? But anyway, concur that regex is not the right tool.

Comment: @MMWizard look for info about `String.Format` or formatting strings in C#, that's what you want.

Comment: Yes i know. but this is for testing only. i can always add a 4th decimal. What i'm trying to accomplish here is that three.js 3d geometry can become pretty big text files and i want to make it a bit smaller by removing the last decimals. If i keep 3 decimals then i have a resolution off 1 mm. And that is enough for a 3d game model. i will also look at combining a Vector3 in 1 float and save the model as PNG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well thanx for you're replies. And in the end it wasn't that difficult. 
I used :
Math.Round(f, 3).ToString("G");

this rounds the float to 3 decimals and format the result into a general format.
see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#GFormatString link.

thanx again

Answer (score 1):

It's indeed more a job for a floor function.

You can use this pattern *(written for a verbatim string)*:

```
\A[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]{0,2}[1-9])?
```

[test online](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5cd%2b(%3f%3a%5c.%5b0-9%5d%7b0%2c2%7d%5b1-9%5d)%3f&i=1234%0d%0a%0d%0a123.4%0d%0a%0d%0a0.1234%0d%0a%0d%0a12.040&o=m)

Comment: i gave it a quick test but it didn't work yet. But i wil look into it tonight at home. thanx